# How to Target Python Server File Using Serial

Tags: python, sockets, arduino

I had a question regarding whether it is possible to directly connect to an IP using Python's socket module. I've tested the code below locally and everything works fine, but have issues when bringing it online (even though my host supports socket). Basically, I run a server.py file on my computer that uses socket to listen for an incoming connection. In a button click, the client will ask the server for permission to run some arduino code. This works locally, but when I try to take it online, it doesn't. I may be missing something in theory here or doing something that requires more knowledge than what I have.

In short, my question is, how can I target that specific file on my computer from online?

```
# I've imported bottle here

import socket
host = '192.XXX.X.XXX' <--this being my computer's IP? Is this possible?
port = 8080

# I have a form that runs this def
# the go is just a way to communicate with the server file, which         
# runs the arduino code

@route('/systems', method='POST')
def syson():
    our_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    our_socket.connect((host, port))
    message = "turn_on_arduino"
    our_socket.send(bytes(message,'UTF-8'))
    reply = our_socket.recv(1024)
    return bottle.redirect("/systems")
```

Thank you

Comment: "have issues" and "doesn't work" are not errors.  Tell what you expected and what you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`192.168.1.xxx` is not your ip .... (well it is but only inside your local network,)

to see your ip(as you are seen to the rest of the internet) go to https://www.whatismyip.com/ ...

**but**  you will probably need to setup some port forwarding rules on your router (each router works different) , or connect your computer directly to your modem without going through a router... this also *assumes* that your ISP does not block inbound connections on whatever port you have selected ...

it would be ***much easier*** for a client to run on your local computer that establishes a connection with the server from client to server...

Comment: Hi Joran. This makes sense. I am reading up on port forwarding right now; particularly, why it's needed. If I go with the easier option, can you tell me how that would work in theory? So I host the client on my computer, but then what? How do I use my web host in that scenario? Thank you again

Comment: heh its way more than i can answer in comments ... basically start the socket listener in a seperate thread(or better yet use websockets) ... your local computer connects to the socket and just waits for the server to send messages ... its really probably easiest (guessing by your skill level) to run a rest api that has the client messages and the (local)client can just poll them and not use a socket at all

Comment: Okay, let me check out websocket and self-study from there. Thank you for taking the time to help. All the best.